# Displaying Mysql data in HTML table format

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a MySQL table with the values "name" and link", and now I try to display this values in a html table.

The table looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="260px"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a></td>
        <td width="260px"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a></td>
        <td width="260px"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a></td>
        <td width="260px"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>...
    </tr>
</table>
```

But now, how can say with PHP that after 4 cells (td) a new row (tr) will create? I know that I need a while statement, but I don't know how.

Comment: You want to work through a basic PHP / mySQL tutorial - they all explain this. This is too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: You should probably use a list (`ul` or `ol`) rather than a table. It does not sound like you have a tabular data structure.

Comment: @Pekka: i searched for this in the internet before, but i doesn't know before that i need a counter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
    $j = 1; // counter
    while ($name_count > $j) 
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) 
        {
              if($name_count < $j) 
                break; //exit from the loop if names are over

        ?>
          <td width="260px"><a href="<?php echo $link;?>" target="_blank" title="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a></td>
        <?php
            $j++;
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a `counter` that will count till 4 and each time `counter%4 == 0` you know that this is the forth cell, and you have to create a new row.

Comment: thanks, i doesn't know about counter before!